# Error in creating android phonegap project on linux fedora

Tags: fedora, android

Actually I am developing an android phonegap project with linux and I have followed the following steps

1. Open Terminal and move to the bin folder present in the android directory, using cd command of terminal.
2. Type the `./create {project_folder_path} {package_name} {project_name}` then press Enter. eg. `./create ~Desktop/myproject com.oodles oodles`

But when I am trying to create a new project it is giving the following error

```
[root@NikhilAgrawal bin]# ./create Desktop/myprojects com.walkover.tester Tester
which: no android in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/Nikhil/.local/bin:/home/Nikhil/bin)
An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/path/to/android-sdk-linux/tools` to your `PATH`, where `/path/to/android-sdk-linux` is the location where you installed the Android SDK in the previous step.

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk-linux/tools"
```

You may want to add `/path/to/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools` as well (it contains `adb`).

Alternatively, create symbolic links to `android` and `adb` in a directory on your `PATH`:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb /path/to/android-sdk-linux/tools/android /usr/local/bin
```

or

```
ln -s /path/to/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb /path/to/android-sdk-linux/tools/android ~/bin
```